# Non-const lvalue reference initialized to prvalue

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initializer

If A is a class-type, the expression A() is a prvalue, correct?
So why is it legal to do

```
A &ARef = A();
```

Also, I found this:

> A reference to T can be initialized with an object of type T, a function of type T, or an object implicitly convertible to T. Once initialized, a reference cannot be changed to refer to another object.
>   References are initialized in the following situations:
>
> **1) When a named lvalue reference variable is declared with an initializer** 
>   [...]

which justifies the action.

I am very new to C++, is an initializer either an expression formed by a call to a constructor or containing the new operator?

Comment: It's *not* legal. If your compiler allows this, discard your compiler.

Comment: The standardese you cite refers to this: `int a; int & b { a };` (This behaviour was clarified in a defect report only after the initial publication of C++11.)

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @NO_NAME Assuredly the notorious one.

Comment: StackOverflow stopper working for me, so I apologize for not answering in time. I use Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: So I am right when I'm saying that A() is a prvalue expression? Also, what exactly is an initializer?

Comment: What you are using is a non-conforming extension provided by Visual Studio. This code should not compile according to the standard. And yes, `A()` is a prvalue expression and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) is what an initializer is.

Comment: So A() as an expression in not an initializer, but int the expression "A a = A()", the subexpression " = A()" is an initializer?

Comment: @user42768 Yes, that is the initializer.